# Django - DateTimeField query on SQLite vs MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

This query returns an empty QuerySet in MySQL, but works in SQLite:

```
commented_this_month = Post.objects.filter(comment__created__month=now.month)
```

My models are really simple:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had generate the mysql.time_zone* tables using the mysql_tzinfo_to_sql utility:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```